# Declaration with multiple declarators - Definition?

Tags: c++, declaration, language-lawyer, definition

Is the following declaration also a definition?

```
int f(), i = 1;
```

If we would rewrite it like this only the second declaration would be a definition:

```
int f();
int i = 1;
```

The c++ standard seems to apply the term definition to entire declarations, but to me it seems like it should be applied to parts of declarations.

Comment: I think the wording in the standard is somewhat incorrect. General consensus would be that your first example is a declaration containing a definition, or that it is two declarations one of which is a definition, but certainly not that the declaration as a whole is a definition.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct about that. The wording in the c++ standard seems to be a bit broken in this case.

Comment: I suppose you could argue that by saying it (as a whole) is not a definition does not preclude that it _contains_ a definition, so in this sense the standard is not actually wrong, just incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each declarator is individually considered to define or merely declare its identifier.

`f()` is only declared. There should be a definition somewhere else.

`i` is defined. A subsequent declaration would need to use `extern` to avoid being a redefinition.

§3.1 *Declarations and definitions* in the C++14 standard says,

> A declaration is a *definition* unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body, it contains the `extern` specifier or…

The paragraph goes on and on with quite a few rules and exceptions. It may perhaps be a defect in the standard that it fails to mention declarators there, despite discussing features that do not immediately appertain to entire declarations.

We also have §8/3,

> Each *init-declarator* in a declaration is analyzed separately as if it was in a declaration by itself.

This could be interpreted to override the "contagious" formulation of rules in §3.1/2.

Comment: Right, but can you justify this according to the wording of the standard? The OP's first example is a (single) declaration according to the C++ grammar, and the standard then goes on to say that "a declaration is a definition unless ..." [basic.def]. According to those rules, the OP's first example is not a definition, because it declares a function without a function body.

Comment: @davmac Yes, I added that to the last paragraph, perhaps before you wrote the comment. Try reloading.

Comment: You've added the quote from [basic.def] which, if correct, would mean that OP's first example is _not_ a definition. That doesn't match with your answer, that says 'i is defined'. Where in the standard does it say that i is defined?

Comment: @davmac The the rules of [basic.def]/2 that refer to properties of declarators, constrain only the immediate declarator. I don't suppose there's anything else in the standard to clarify this point, so I have no further comment except that the reviewers of that text probably didn't consider the most literal interpretation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter read your quote from the standard - it doesn't say _declarator_, it says _declaration_. That's the issue. I agree that your interpretation is the correct one, but the wording of the standard doesn't support it. (Ok, your amended answer is good now).

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, I think §8/3 is the key to solving this problem, but it seems like they forgot that init-declarators are not the only part of a declaration where entities can be declared. For example the declaration extern class A {} a; if in the declarative region of the global namespace, defines A and declares a.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are equivalent statements. In both cases, it is declaration for the function f() and declaration + definition for the variable i.

Answer (score -1):

This declaration

```
int f(), i = 1;
```

contains two declarations and one definition. That is it declares a function and it declares and at the same time defines an object.

A function definition is a function declaration that includes its body. However in the declaration above the function does not includes its body. So it is only a declaration of function `f` with unknown number of parameters if it is a C declaration or without parameters if it is a C++ declaration..

As for variable `i` then this declaration is at the same time a definition of the variable because a memory is reserved for the corresponding object of type `int` and moreover the reserved memory is initialized by integer constant `1`.

From the C Standard (6.7 Declarations)

> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set
>   of identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for
>   that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body

Comment: "This declaration ... contains two declarations". You see the problem? :p

Comment: @davmac  No, I do not see a problem. And what problem do you see?

Comment: @davmac  Here is only one problem that is related to your lack of knowledge of C. In C declarations are not statements. So this line is a declaration. At the same time it contains declarations of two identifiers.

Comment: You are saying that a declaration contains declarations. That's not the case.

Comment: @davmac  See my preceding comment.

Comment: I didn't say the declaration was a statement. I said that it doesn't contain declarations, which is most certainly correct. The relevant grammar for a declaration is in given in 6.7 (the same section you quote from).

Comment: @davmac  The identifiers are declared are not they? So this line contains declarations of two identifiers. There is no problem with my statement nor with the C Standard. There is only one problem with your common sense.

Comment: Yes, the identifiers are declared, and yes the line contains a declaration of two identifiers - but it's only a single declaration, not multiple declarations.

Comment: @davmac  One more there is only problem with your common sense and lack of knowledge of the C Standard. Identifiers are declared. So  you have as many identifiers  as there are many their declarations in the program.

Comment: @davmac: No I did not, it was Vlad from Moscow that changed my tagging. I was only interested in c++ here.

Comment: @Supremum Ahh, my mistake. I've removed the tag now.

Comment: @Vlad according to the text in the C standard, the line `int f(), i = 1;` is a single _declaration_, which declares multiple _declarators_ (identified by f and i). But regardless, why did you add a C tag to this question, which was intended for C++, and then proceed to answer it for C?

Comment: @davmac  One more you totally do not understand the Standard and  it seems has a problem with your intellect. The notion of a declaration is two-fold in the C Standard. For example there is written (quote) "A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.". This quote does not mean the C construction named declaration. This function prototype you can declare in one declaration (as a language construction) or with other function prototypes in the same construction of declaration.

Comment: @davmac  Nevertheless the declaration of the function prototype does not depend on whether it will be declared separatly or with other declaration of function prototypes. In C++ declarations (language construction) are statements. So I could write that this STATEMENT contains several DECLARATIONS. However in C declarations like language constaructions are not statements. So i wrote that vthis DECLARATION (language construction) containsw several DECLARATIONS (announcements) of iidentifiers.

Comment: @davmac  I am sorry but it is obvious that you are a very weak programmer that knows neither C nor C++ Standard and the worst  are even unable to understand what are written in these documents. So I do not see a sense to continue the discussion.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow indeed there is no point continuing, since you have resorted to insults rather than a reasoned discussion.

Comment: @davmac  Each identifier shall be declared. That is each identifier shall have a declaration. This notion of declaration has nothing common with the way how it will be declared. whether you will use one C or C++ construction (in C it is a declaration while in C++ it can be named statement) for declarations of several identifiers or several constructions fpr each declaration of identifiers. Shortly speaking there is a notion of declaration and there is a mechanism how this notion can be implemented.

Comment: @davmac  And moreover one declaration can contain several DEFINITIONS. At the same time a definition is a DECLARATION. So one declaration (as mechanism) can contain several DECLARATIONS as the notion.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm really not interested in further discussion, thanks.